# Compounding different retrieved data in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I have a problem because the requirements with the system I'm developing right now needs to compound two different data, it means that two different retrieved data from the database would be displayed in one same row and column, is it possible?
I would appreciate your answers, thanks! I would like to join Filename and FA status in one same row and column, how will I do it?

here is my code below :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">Outbound Transactions</div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive spacer">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Receiver</th>
                        <th>Send Date</th>
                        <th>Filename</th>
                        <th>ISA</th>
                        <th>GS</th>
                        <th>Trans</th>
                        <th>Sender ID</th>
                        <th>Receiver ID</th>
                        <th>FA Status</th>
                        <th style="width: 5%;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    {% if transaction != null %}
                        {% for trans in transaction %}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 8%;">
                                  {{ render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getTradingPartnerName', {'timexID' : trans.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'customerID' : trans.ediTransaction.senderId })) }}
                                </td>

                                {% 
                                   set result=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getFile', {'fileName' : trans.ediTransaction.fileName, 'senderId': trans.ediTransaction.senderId , 'receiverId' : trans.ediTransaction.receiverId, 'gsNumber' : trans.ediTransaction}))|split('+', 4)
                                %}

                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ result[0] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 30%;">{{ result[3] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ result[2] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 5%;">{{ result[1] }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 3%;">{{ trans.noOfTrans }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ trans.ediTransaction.receiverId }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 7%;">{{ trans.ediTransaction.senderId }}</td>
                                <td style="width: 8%;">
                                    {% if trans.errorCodeId == 2 %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Accepted but <br/>errors were <br/>noted</span>
                                    {% elseif trans.errorCodeId == 3 %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Partially<br/> Accepted</span><br/><br/>
                                            {{ trans.acceptedTrans }} Accepted,<br/>
                                            {{ trans.noOfTrans - trans.acceptedTrans }} Rejected
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span style="background-color: yellow;">Rejected</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <br/><br/>

                                    {% 
                                        set error=render(controller('MatrixEdiBundle:Matrix:getError', {'id': trans.edi997DetailId }))|split('+') 
                                    %}
                                    <span>
                                        <p style="white-space: normal;">
                                            {% if error[0] != "0" %}
                                                {{ error[0] }}{{ "%02d"|format(error[1]) }}<br/>
                                                {{ error[2] }}
                                            {% else %}
                                                Errors were not specified in 997 file
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </p>
                                    </span>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                  <a href="" data-href="{{ path('matrix_edi_deleteFile', { 'id':trans.ediTransaction.ediTransactionId,'filename': trans.ediTransaction.fileName, 'url': 'matrix_edi_rejectedOutboundTrans' }) }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><center><i class="fa fa-trash o" style="color:#1975A3;"></i></center></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="15" class="alignment result"> No Result Found </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
                <div class="panel-footer"> 
      {% if transaction | length > 0 and pagination['pages_count'] is defined and pagination['pages_count'] > 0 %}
          {#-----------------Pager------------------#}
```

Comment: You can create your own array of structured data and pass it to the view

Comment: @goto, thanks for the idea, i already solved the problem, .